# iText unicode in annotaion

Tags: java, unicode, annotations, itext

I'm using Itext in java.

Please give me an example to add a text annotation which contains unicode string in content to pdf.

Thanks.

Comment: I have searched that itext support unicode in annotation. But I don't know how to add a text annotation which contain unicode character.

Comment: try writing some code...

Comment: Are there any way to set font for annotation?

Comment: I'm new to itext. I don't found method in Annotation class to set font.

Comment: According to the PDF specification on Text Annotations, "when open, it shall display a pop-up window containing the text of the note in a font and size chosen by the conforming reader." Thus, there wont be a font to set.

Comment: How can i force those popup to show the text of the note which contain some unicode characters?

Comment: See my answer, the use of excessive force was not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a simple sample adding a text annotation to an existing PDF; both the title and the content of the text annotation contain arabic characters.

```
import java.io.*;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*;

public class TestAnnotations extends TestCase
{
    // a phonetic approximation
    final static String LAWRENCE_OF_ARABIA = "\u0644\u0648\u0631\u0627\u0646\u0633\u0627\u0644\u0639\u0631\u0628";

    public void testUnicodeAnnotation() throws Exception
    {
        final PdfReader origPdfReader = new PdfReader("test.pdf");
        final OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("test-annot.pdf");
        final PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(origPdfReader, outputStream, '\0', true);

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100);
        PdfAnnotation annotation = PdfAnnotation.createText(pdfStamper.getWriter(), rect, LAWRENCE_OF_ARABIA, LAWRENCE_OF_ARABIA, true, "Help");
        pdfStamper.addAnnotation(annotation, 1);
        pdfStamper.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

[image: Sample result]

Comment: If you consider your question appropriately answered, please mark the answer as "accepted answer", cf. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Shouldn't the text be right-aligned?  Is that something you have to specify separately?

Comment: @bmm6o I have no idea how it *should* be aligned. `PdfAnnotation.createText` does not create appearances. Thus, the way the text is displayed depends on the PDF viewer used and maybe even its configuration or variant.