# Non-ASCII alternate text

Tags: java, image, unicode, itext7, alternate

I am using the following code to set an alternate text for an image:

```
img.getAccessibilityProperties().setAlternateDescription(altText);
```

where `img` is, of course, a `com.itextpdf.layout.element.Image`

When the text is non-ASCII (e.g. Hebrew or Russian) the alt text is displayed as gibberish. It seems that the high-order byte of the unicode char is simply stripped off - e.g. from 05EA, just EA enters the PDF.
I know that PDF supports non-ASCII alternate text - how is it possible to create them using iText?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266139/itext-unicode-in-annotaion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be using an outdated version of `iText7`. There indeed was a bug with proper writing of alternate descriptions, but it was fixed in May 2017 and the fix is already available in the latest `7.0.4` release.

Please update to the latest version.

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot!